# Make rows into column with awk or sed

Tags: linux, scripting

Recently, I look for scripts to take this:

```
This;
Is;
First;
Line;
```

and make it like:

```
This Is First Line
```

Comment: Do you want to put everything on a single line? If not, when does the second line start?

Answer (score 1):

Neither awk nor sed, but how about `tr` instead:

```
printf 'This;\nIs;\nFirst;\nLine;\n' | 
    tr -s ';[:space:]' '[ *]'
```

Output: `This is First Line`

Comment: Sorry, I have tried this commands but the result is not my wanted. In fact, the file containts more records like:

Comment: @AlanFok You should put what you want in the question if you want people to be able to help you.

Comment: In fact, the file contains more data and have to convert into columns as CSV file.

Comment: @AlanFok What I meant was that the question that you *posted* has been answered.  If that's not what you really wanted to ask, update the question.  Don't expect people to read your mind or know what your system looks like.

Comment: 1) In `tr` `[[:space:]]` means "opening bracket character, any space character, closing bracket character". 2) While using `-s` no need for `*`. So `tr -s ';[:space:]' ' '` would be enough.

Comment: @manatwork Thanks.  The `*` is kept in for [maximum portability](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html#tag_20_132_16).

Comment: Good point @jw013.

Answer (score 0):

Your example shows spaces between fields, but you mention "CSV", which means Comma Seperated Values...  I've used spaces. Just change `/ /` to `/,/` if you want commas.

Input file contains:

```
This;
Is;
First;
Line;
This;
Is;
Second;
Line;
```

The script:

```
 sed -nr 'N; N; N; s/;\n/ /g; s/;$//p' file
```

Output:

```
This Is First Line
This Is Second Line
```